# Android Calculate Remaining time of battery and subsytems.

Tags: android, battery

I wanted to calculate the remaining hours of battery and subsystem as talk time, websurfing, audio playback, video playback and standby.

I used reflection to get private class **com.android.internal.os.PowerProfile** and **android.os.BatteryStats**.

I followed Android's battery setting 
http://netmite.com/android/mydroid/donut/packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/fuelgauge/PowerUsageSummary.java

to get remaining hours of battery

with method:

```
long computeBatteryRealtime(long curTime, int which);
```

with:

```
curTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() * 1000;
which = STATS_UNPLUGGED
```

But the return value was wrong, a few minutes. Do I use this method right ?

Comment: I also suffer from this problem. If you find the solution please give me. I really appreciate.